# How can I reproduce the dist function

Tags: r, function, distance

I simulated a data frame of points, x and y values, for various calculations. The dist function works pretty well to calculate the distances between every possible combination. And I've been trying to reproduce a simplified version that only does that (getting a Euclidean distance matrix of a data frame) but it hasn't been working so far.

If I was entering the two columns, I would do something like this but I'm trying to use just one input, the data frame.

```
dist <- function(x,y) {
  distance <- sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))
  return(distance)
}
```

I've tried using the source code for dist but I can't figure out to strip away all the stuff I dont want without breaking it.

```
function (x, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, 
  p = 2) 
{
  if (!is.na(pmatch(method, "euclidian"))) 
    method <- "euclidean"
  METHODS <- c("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", 
    "binary", "minkowski")
  method <- pmatch(method, METHODS)
  if (is.na(method)) 
    stop("invalid distance method")
  if (method == -1) 
    stop("ambiguous distance method")
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  N <- nrow(x)
  attrs <- if (method == 6L) 
    list(Size = N, Labels = dimnames(x)[[1L]], Diag = diag, 
      Upper = upper, method = METHODS[method], p = p, 
      call = match.call(), class = "dist")
  else list(Size = N, Labels = dimnames(x)[[1L]], Diag = diag, 
    Upper = upper, method = METHODS[method], call = match.call(), 
    class = "dist")
  .Call(C_Cdist, x, method, attrs, p)
}
```

Is anyone able to point me to a viable first step? I'm really trying to learn how to program without always relying on pre-packaged functions.

Comment: Sample data and expected output, please.

Comment: Just a small comment on that: the `.Call` calls a new function `C_Cdist` which actually does the work you want to do (in **C**). So, to understand how the original `dist` function works you should look into that function. The stuff before is just to choose the correct method and doing some preparation stuff. See here for further information on `.Call` https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/11/using-r-callhello/

Comment: I simulated the data with rnorm and the expected output is the output of the dist(x) where x is the data frame

Answer (score 1):

You could use `outer`

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
outer(df$x, df$y, function(x, y)sqrt((x - y)^2))
```

Comment: I don't understand. What role does function() play here?

Comment: Ignore that, I checked the documentation. Thank you, that makes complete sense except the output is different from dist()

Comment: I also want to mention in case it was unclear that I want the distance between every possible combination of p's and q's (rows). The X and Y variables are coordinates.